# Make a program that can simulate a key press

Tags: vb.net

I'm a noob in VB when it comes to this. I want to make a program that can simulate a key press like a human is typing. For example:

I want the programm to type at about the speed of 60 Words per minute the string: "This is a a test.".

Any ideas? Thanks Guys!

Comment: What have you tries so far? This site is for helping not for **doing** the job.

Comment: at a very high level, you'll want to store your strings to an array/dictionary/etc. and look into using a timer to determine when to update the display with the text, above and beyond that we need to see what you have thus far.

Comment: Thanks. I'll work on it tomorrow. I'll get some sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is an easy way to write 60 words per minute but try this.

```
Dim str As String = "Your Text"
Public Sub type(ByVal int As Double)
    For Each c As Char In str
        SendKeys.Send(c)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(int * 1000)
    Next
End Sub
```

Example: `type(1)` will type `Your Text` with 1 second delay between each character. And `type(0.155)` will write **ALMOST** 60 WPM. :)

Comment: is that applicable for all keyboards button? @banforfun